# How to limit my output to false statements?

Tags: python

enter code hereMy code takes the numbers in range 500-100000 and tests them for primality twice. Once with fermit's little theorem and again with a better primality test. The output given is every number identified as prime in fermits and next to it, its correct primality in the form of true=prime and false=not prime for example:2753 is prime True,
2767 is prime True,
2777 is prime True,
2779 is prime False,
2789 is prime True,
What I need to know is how do I only output the ones that are false? I can't change the functions I called on.

```
    from exactPrimalityTest import *
    import random
    from fastPowerMod import *
    for n in range(500,100001):
        a = random.randint(1,n-1)
        for i in range(10):
            if (fastPowerMod(a,n-1, n) != 1):
                break
        else:
            print n, "is prime", exactPrimalityTest(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

add this check before you print

```
res = exactPrimalityTest(n)
if not res:
    print n, "is prime", res
```

Answer (score 0):

in your last else: statement, assign the exactPrimality return to a var and do an if.

.....

```
else:
    primality = exactPrimalityTest(n)
    if not primality:
        print n, "is prime", primality
```

sorry, haven't used python in a while, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score -1):

```
from exactPrimalityTest import *
import random
from fastPowerMod import *
for n in range(500,100001):
    a = random.randint(1,n-1)
        for i in range(10):
        if (fastPowerMod(a,n-1, n) != 1):
            break
    else:
        if exactPrimalityTest(n) == False:
            print n, "is prime False"
```

Comment: this will calculate `exactPrimalityTest(n)` twice